# "[Edit]" shortlink is changed to lowercase at the begining of a sentence

Tags: bug, comments, short-links, capitalization

The comment below this post contains a sentence starting with "[Edit]".

The system changes it to a lower case 'edit'.

Comment: Not that is really important. [Edit] the question. It could also be that this is a subtle hint that I should write '*Please* [edit]'.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue. While "please [edit]" might sound nicer than "[edit]", i usually write it in the form of "[Edit]ing this question for xyz would improve it", and find it annoying to have to rephrase.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see a problem there, because *usually* [edit] is used in the middle of sentences (it is even more simple for me to start a sentence with something else than [edit]), like:

> Please [edit] your question to include what have you tried.
>
> Answers are not for additional information, please [edit] your question instead.

I think you can always rephrase your comment to put [edit] not at the beginning of the sentence.

Also, there are no capitalised magic links, as I know.